# alfresco - get noderef of uploaded file

Tags: java, alfresco

I am trying to get the node ref of file uploaded to default root directory in my java class.

I tried [this](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/NodeRef_cookbook#Getting_a_NodeRef_from_its_path) link.

But it is returning empty result set. How can I write search query to get the particular file node. Or Is there any way to create node ref from sting in java class.

My code :

```
NodeRef companyHomeNodeRef = null;
            StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE,
                    "SpacesStore");

            ResultSet rs = searchService.query(storeRef,
                    SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE, "\\\"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/sys:boris/cm:mypics\\");

            try {
                System.out.println("length :" + rs.length());
                if (rs.length() == 0) {
                    // throw new Exception("Didn't find Company Home");
                } else {
                    companyHomeNodeRef = rs.getNodeRef(0);
                }
            } finally {
                rs.close();
            }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Below is code to create node ref of file from node ref string and update the content of file.

```
           AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new RunAsWork<String>() {

                @Override
                public String doWork() throws Exception {

                    NodeRef nodeRef = new NodeRef("workspace://SpacesStore/f1a5e908-80cb-4c6e-b919-cc80fe53b835");
                    if(contentService != null) {
                        ContentWriter writer = contentService.getWriter(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
                        if(writer != null) {
                            writer.putContent(new ByteArrayInputStream("updated content".getBytes()));
                        } 
                    } 
                    return null;
                }

            }, AuthenticationUtil.getSystemUserName());
```

Comment: I don't get it, where did the magic noderef string appear from?

Comment: The page where I am using this code, I have node ref string. As I am new to alfresco, earlier I was struggling with creating node ref for file. Also, the my original code was not working, even tried with query tested in query browser.

Answer (score 2):

Your Lucene search syntax is incorrect. If you want the folder where the picture was uploaded, you'd use this:
PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:boris/cm:mypics"

If you want the objects sitting in that folder, you would use this:
PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:boris/cm:mypics/*"

And if you want a specific object in that folder, you'd use this:
PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:boris/cm:mypics/cm:test.png"

A good tool for testing your queries is the Node Browser, available in both Alfresco Explorer and Alfresco Share. Be sure to select "Lucene" as the search syntax, then try out your queries. Once they return the object you are looking for, plug it into your Java code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the all of the tutorials you have written. Those are very helpful from the beginning. My file is located at repository/sites/mysite/documentlibrary/myfolder/myfile. I am trying PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:mysite/cm:doclib/cm:myfolder/cm:myfile". but is not showing any results for me. The query "PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:mysite" is showing cm:doclib node under it. Am I missing something ? Can you please explain me with example for better understanding. Is app:user_homes is default one. I could not see this directory anywhere in hierarchy.

Comment: Jeff, above java code is returning empty result set for this "PATH:"/app:company_home" query. The same is working in node browser. Do I need to update the java code ?? Actually my goal is to get the node ref for file and update its content from java code. Is there any better option to do this ??

Comment: mahesh, if you have not already done so, go look at the Node Browser. In Alfresco Explorer, it is in the Admin Console. In Share, it is under "More, Application". The Node Browser will help you make sense of the hierarchical structure of the repo. For example, if your file lives under repository/sites/mysite/documentlibrary/myfolder/myfile, the path would be /app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mysite/cm:documentLibrary/cm:myfolder/cm:myfile.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, now query is giving desired results at node browser. But not working through above java class . Do I need to modify above code ?? Please help me. I am in big trouble...

Comment: Jeff, I am facing strange behavior from node browser. It is showing me results for one particular query(file) only. For rest of the files in the same hierarchy, it is displaying no results found message.How can I fix this ??